# Does sklearn perform feature selection within cross validation?

Tags: scikit-learn, feature-selection, cross-validation, gridsearchcv

I would like to add a feature selector on my pipeline and use gridsearchcv to tune both the hyperparameters of the selector and the classifier(s).

I am wondering if sklearn performs feature selection within cross validation. For example lets say that I want to perform forward selection using the `SequentialFeatureSelector` and one of the configurations of the grid is a random forest with 150 estimators and min_samples_leaf 10.

Does the `SequentialFeatureSelector` or any other `Selector` in sklearn performs the feature selection on each fold?

That is, if i have 3 features and perform 5-fold cv, does this mean that sklearn will train 15 models in order to select the first feature?

**Edit**
I am adding the code that I have currently written. This performs a univariate feature selection with `SelectKBest`.

```
import numpy as np
import joblib
import json
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
from sklearn.feature_selection import SelectKBest, SequentialFeatureSelector
from sklearn.feature_selection import f_classif, mutual_info_classif
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
from sklearn.svm import SVC
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV, train_test_split

# For reproducible results
np.random.seed(1)

# Importing the df
df = pd.read_csv('data.csv')
df.set_index('MOF Name', inplace=True)

X, y = df.iloc[:, :-1], df.iloc[:, -1] # Target is the last column

# Split to train and test set with stratification
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(
    X, y, stratify=y, train_size=0.8
    )

# Define the pipeline
steps = [
    ('selector', SelectKBest()),
    ('scaler', StandardScaler()),
    ('classifier', SVC())
    ]

pipeline = Pipeline(steps)

# Selector(s) hyperparameters
kbest_params = {
    'selector__k': [2, 3, 4],
    'selector__score_func': [f_classif, mutual_info_classif],
}

sequential_params = ...

# SVC hyperparameters
svc_params = {
    'classifier__kernel': ['linear', 'rbf'],
    'classifier__C': [0.001, 0.01, 0.1, 1.0, 10, 100],
    'classifier__gamma': [0.01, 1, 5, 10],
}

# RF hyperparameters
rf_params = {
    'classifier__n_estimators': [100, 150, 200],
    'classifier__min_samples_leaf': [1, 5, 10, 20],
    'classifier__class_weight': ['balanced', None],
    'classifier__max_features': ['sqrt', None],
}

# Define the grid of hyperparameters
param_grid = [
    {**kbest_params, **clf_params} for clf_params in [svc_params, rf_params]
    ]

# Perform cross-valdiation for tuning hyperparameters
grid_search = GridSearchCV(
estimator=pipeline, param_grid=param_grid, scoring='roc_auc', verbose=2
    )

grid_search.fit(X_train, y_train)

# Save df and final model
df = [X_train, y_train, X_test, y_test, grid_search]
with open('cv_results', 'wb') as fhand:
    joblib.dump(df, fhand)
```

I have set `verbose=2` and I get the output

> Fitting 5 folds for each of 288 candidates, totalling 1440 fits

which is consistent with the number of hyperparameters that I am examining (note that parameters for random forest have been commented out).

Is there any idea on how to perform feature selection in a similar way? That is, perform `SequentialFeatureSelector` for each configuration of the grid within cross validation?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for providing code. Are you sure you really want to: perform `SequentialFeatureSelector` for each configuration of the grid within cross validation?

Do you realize that will be super slow because `SequentialFeatureSelector` will train many models (it is iterative method with number of iterations == number of features you have and each iteration will do yet another cross-validation which trains multiple models)?

Normally what people do in your situation is:
First do the hyperparameter tuning to find good hyperparameters for full dataset, where in your case you should just treat the `SelectKBest` arguments as additional hyperparameters to optimize (consider different values of `k` and different values of `score_func`: f_classif, mutual_info_classif, chi2).

Then fix your estimator with the best hyperparameter values and run `SequentialFeatureSelector` with these hyperparameters fixed.
Finally after you have finalized your feature-set, hold it fixed, and you can run the hyperparameter optimization one more time with estimator fit to reduced feature set (this time removing `SelectKBest` from your pipeline).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Indeed it will be very computational heavy. I will try `SequentialFeatureSelector` with some esimator or `SelectFromModel` with lasso logistic regression, and play with hyperparameters such as `tol` and `n_features_to_select`.  But the selectors are applied separately at each cv-fold since it is part of the pipeline , right?